# Lightswitch: All entities in a screen must be exposed via one domain service?

Tags: wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have two entities. Order and OrderLine. One Order can have many OrderLines.
Each entity was exposed via its own RIA service. Their Read methods return IEnumerable and IEnumerable. LightSwitch correctly read both services and created data sources.
When I created a List Detail Screen for Order and added a query as a data item for OrderLines the read operations worked well but the OrderLines controls were allways read-only.

So I tried to put both entities and their logic into one domain service (I didn't think it was the right way, because I knew that LS would not create a relation between two entities in one container). I created the same screen the same way (ListDetail for Order and manually add a query for OrderLines). Now I can edit even my OrderLines.

Please, can somebody confirm my empirically found statement that "All entities that should be editable in one screen must be exposed via the same RIA service?"

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could have made it work if you used code like this to the _InitializeDataWorkspace method:

saveChangesTo.Add(this.DataWorkspace.MyOtherDataSource

see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2011/01/05/using-both-remote-and-local-data-in-a-lightswitch-application.aspx

Comment: thank you very much Michael, I'll shurely take a look at that link. Now I work on another project, so I will be able to test it later on...

I'll post back.